# Анимация изменения Scene в JavaFX

Tags: анимация, java, javafx

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос такой. Есть приложение, написанное с использованием JavaFX, в котором при нажатии на кнопку заменяется объект Scene на новый через `stage.setScene(nextScene)`, этакое переключение между окнами, как в установочном визарде. Возможно ли как-то прикрутить какую-либо анимацию к этому действу? То есть, например, затемнение исходной сцены, а затем уже при нарастании яркости видна следующая сцена.

И является ли такой подход (изменение сцен через `setScene()`) нормальным? Может есть какие-то ещё варианты?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Странный глючок - пришло оповещение на мыльницу, что мол есть ответ, прихожу сюда - нет ответа. Отвечавший, отзовитесь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам. Я поменял концепцию. В итоге получилось вот что: я создал все содержимое окон без учета объектов Scene и тому подобного. Я создал контроллер наследуясь от StackPane, который хранит root-компоненты(разумеется, со всем содержимым) для каждого окна в HashMap. Для нашего Stage-объекта мы создаем единственный Scene-объект, в котором root-объектом является наш контроллер. Фокус вот в чем. Когда изменяется содержимое окна, контроллер удаляет всех "детей" StackPane-контроллера, и добавляет в него извлеченный из HashMap нужный мне root-объект. Не сложно приделать к этому анимацию из разряда Timeline. Сие решение является частично переработанным решением найденным [здесь](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1). В итоге меняется не сцена, а её содержимое.